# Problem with Android Studio - Does not detect any smartphone

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Hello everyone and thank you for your time reading this.

I have a problem with Android Studio in a portatil PC. I installed the latest version and set up ADB, SDKs, JRE... as always. I then clone a project from my other PC and when i try to run it on my physic smartphone, it does not appear on the devices list. Things that i already tried:

- "Trubleshoot Device Connections" option on Android Studio: It detects my phone in the first step but there is none after the 3rd where i can "Restart ADB server", no device is found.
- Checked that everything is correct within my smartphone: Debug is ON, i accepted the message to allow the PC and I even restart everything.
- Using ADB from command line, the command `adb devices` correctly detects my phone, but it does not appear in the Android Studio dropdown menu. Performing `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` does not help.
- Restarting Android Studio, smartphone and PC does not solve the problem, neither does "Invalidate Cahes / Restart...".
- Creating a new project from scract or configuring the project in any way does not solve the problem.
- I do not have Flutter installed in any PC (my main PC works perfectly with all phones).
- I tried downloading specific SDK versions and deleting-installing SDKs, tools and so in the 'SDK Manager'.
- I tried changing the Gradle version both in the project and in the Gradle file.
- I review the options available on "Run/Debug Configurations" and there is no "Target" option, but i tried everything there without solution.
- Make, build, clean... does not solve the problem.
- Tried also downloading the exact same version of Android Studio that I am using in my main PC but it returns the same error.
- I tried 4 smartphones that works on my main PC but Android Studio does not detect any of them (ADB detects all of them from command line).

I am now out of ideas, can someone help me? I will add here more information as I am trying to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to install your device specific drivers on PC first

Comment: @UmerFarooq please specify, because i never need that in any pc i have.

Comment: When you connect your device to PC, your device with the name should appear in windows > device manager (along with ADB interface). If your device isn't appearing in the device manager panel it means you don't have your device drivers installed. You can get your phones drivers from their official webpage

Comment: Same problem recently happed to me, installing device driver solved my issue

Comment: my device is correctly detected in the windows file system, in the device section and in the ADB list

Answer (score 0):

It may be related on your USB cable. I had that problem because my cable didn't allow data transfering. Try buying a new one which has data transfering available.
Also check out if your PC can see the smartphone from file explorer at first.

Comment: Checked that, tested with 3 cables that worked on my main PC, but they do not work on the portatil.